# Random sum - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, numbers

How do I make this actually give me an answer? I want it to output a sum, something like " 17-5=12 "

```
    import random
    no1 =(random.randint(1,20))
    function =(random.choice("+-*"))
    no2 =(random.randint(1,20))
    answer =no2,function,no1
    print(answer)
```

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` may be useful to you. (but only for 3.X)

Comment: Thank you but how do I use it?

Comment: The documentation should provide some guidance there :-)

Comment: okay, where do I use it then? :-) sorry, I'm really not too great at this yet

Comment: the right answer is probably to use a dictionary to look up a function based on the operator" (or `function` in this case) and apply that function to the numbers

Comment: where you say `print` you would use a method to evaluate your expression

Comment: @Kevin not terribly useful, as it will only evaluate the numbers (which you can do with `int`) **not** the operators.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I mean you should use `literal_eval` once, on the entire expression, rather than once per number. (although I recognize that `literal_eval("2+2")` working properly in 3.x may be an implementation detail, as the documentation doesn't explicitly mention that operators are allowed)

Comment: It has been pointed out to me that in versions 3.2 and above, `literal_eval` secretly works on "+" and "-" operations, but not "*". I retract my suggestion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like so:

```
import random
no1 =(random.randint(1,20))
function =(random.choice("+-*"))
no2 =(random.randint(1,20))
answer =str(no1) + function + str(no2)
print(str(no1) + function + str(no2) + '=' + str(eval(answer)))
```

Comment: I wrote this in 2.x, it should work with 3.x as well

Comment: I had one problem ... I thought ... I know I'll use `eval` now I have 2 problems

Comment: Obligatory disclaimer: `eval` should not be used on any string that the user is capable of manipulating, since they could provide input like `"__import__('os').system('delete_hard_drive.exe')"` and brick your computer. However, there doesn't seem to be a danger for _this particular_ exercise, since the user can't supply their own values.

Answer (score 2):

first know there are functions to help perform operations

```
import operator
operator.add(5,7) # 12
operator.sub(5,7) # -2
operator.mul(5,7) # 35
```

you should create a mapping of operators to functions

```
import operator

my_functions = {"+":operator.add,"-":operator.sub,"*":operator.mul}
```

then you can select an operator and a function easily

```
my_operator,my_function = random.choice(my_functions.items())
```

then all you need to do is apply it to your numbers (of coarse your numbers must be numbers first)

```
number1 = 12
number2 = 5

print("%s %s %s = %s"%(number1,my_operator,number2,my_function(number1,number2)))
```

Comment: no .... not at all ... eval is a dirty hack ... imho at least (but your right in the fact it solves op's problem) (mine however did have a typo on the `print`)